# name every column in a table excel/vba

Tags: vba, excel, loops, named

I am trying to name each column in an excel spreadsheet by their header. For instance, if a column has the header "cat" I want the column to be named "cat". That way I can refer to cat in a formula, rather than specifying the column with A:A.

I can do this just fine with a single column, but when I try to do it with many my procedure fails. Here's my code.

```
Sub defineName()

Dim numColumns As Long
Range("A1").Select
numColumns = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column



Columns("A:A").Select
For cat = 0 To numColumns
    Selection.Offset(0, I).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=cat1, RefersToR1C1:="activesheet.cat1"
Next cat
End Sub
```

Im pretty sure my problem is this part

```
 Name:=cat1, RefersToR1C1:="activesheet.cat1"
```

and it is not iterating like I think it is.

I almost wish I could

```
 Name:=[cat]1, RefersToR1C1:="activesheet.[cat]1"
```

but that does not work either. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: You can do this directly from the Formula Menu, using Create from Selection, and of course can be converted to VBA.

Comment: I don't think this is quite what you want to do. You'll probably notice a huge performance hit doing this. When you use `A:A` in formulas Excel finds the last row (if it's not an array formula) and only considers beginning to end of your data range not all 1048576 cells; when you name the range it is going to calculate using every cell in that range. Now what you could do is convert your data set to a table. You can then reference it like `Table1[[#All],[cat]]` This will also automatically do what you are asking so no need for VBA

Comment: I was going to suggest the natural language formula which appear in XL97.... it vanished again in XL07 though.  It's a poorer sibling of the tables that @Tom suggests. https://bettersolutions.com/excel/named-ranges/natural-language-formulas.htm

Comment: I did not know about that functionality. thank you @tom

Answer (score 1):

See my suggestion above, but here is alternative code. Naming the whole column though doesn't seem very efficient. Having seen Tom's suggestion, I think that is a better approach.

```
Sub defineName()

Dim numColumns As Long, cat As Long

numColumns = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For cat = 1 To numColumns
    Columns(cat).Name = Cells(1, cat)
Next cat

End Sub
```